# Regex for not allowing specific domain email id angular js

Tags: angularjs, regex, validation

I want to show error message if user enter the email from few specific doamins. I tried this but didn't work out.

```
Email <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="txtmail" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.)?(?!(domain|domain1|domain3))\.com$/" required />
```

xyz@domain.com or 
xyz@DOMAIN.com should not be allowed.

Comment: `\.com$` requires the string to end with `.com`, and it is certainly not `omnitracs`, `xrscorp`, nor `roadnet`, you misused the lookahead here. You need custom logic here, use `\.([^.]+)$` and inspect the group value inside code.

Comment: xyz.domain.com or xyz.DOMAIN.com not be allowed. Is it xyz@domain.com or xyz@DOMAIN.com no ?

Comment: yes @sgrillon it was typo error

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you help me to correct that regex. I want to use it with ng-pattern

Comment: You can't do it with just `ng-pattern` regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript:

```
const regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@((domain|domain1|domain)).com$/;
const str = `xyz@domain1.com`;
let m;

if ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

[Online sample here](https://regex101.com/r/9iLfck/2/)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: see new screeshot, domain.com is OK

Comment: Nope still it is passing xyz@domain.com which is wrong

Comment: @Rahulgupta, you do not read the good link (version 2): https://regex101.com/r/9iLfck/2/  see the scrennshot number 3 (1 match, 19 steps)

Answer (score 2):

You can check the mail address via external JavaScript function:

```js
let success = () => {console.log("Valid address")};
let fail    = () => {console.log("ERROR - Invalid address")};
let regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.)?(domain|domain1|domain3)\.com$/g;

function checkInput(element) {
  if(regex.test(element.value)) {
    fail();
  }
  else {
    success();
  }
}
```

```html
Email <input type="text" name="email" onchange="checkInput(this)" ng-model="txtmail" required />
```

Comment: for every email it says invalid

Comment: nope its taking xyz@domain.com as valid which should be invalid

Comment: I've edited your regex to `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.)?[a-zA-Z]+\.)?(domain|domain1|domain3)\.com$/g` - now it works.